# SQL ERROR: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the below MySQL query which is returning bool false when doing var_dump. The mySQL statement is correct as I tested in phpMyAdmin. Any suggestions to fix this please?

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT enBody FROM page WHERE pageName='wine'";
    $en = $db->query($sql);

    var_dump($enOutput=mysqli_fetch_assoc($en));
    var_dump($en);//returns bool false too
    while($enOutput=mysqli_fetch_assoc($en)) :
        $enDisplay=$enOutput['enBody'];                 
        echo $enDisplay;
    endwhile;
```

Comment: Try this instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`: *$enOutput = $en->fetch_assoc()*, test what happens, please.

Comment: @BilalAhmed There are no duplicates.

Comment: @Rafael the problem I think its further up when I am saving query in $en

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the connection string. There was the database name which was different, missing one capital character....stupid me. apologies and thanks all

Answer (score -1):

The best guess would be SQL query is unable to find the requested rows so it's returning by assuming you don't have any error in sql query.
if You aren't sure about query then use this to check by replacing the query with this

```
$sql = "SELECT enBody FROM page WHERE pageName='wine'";
$result= $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

null and **mysqli_fetch_assoc** only accepts **mysqli result**

So you just need to put a basic **if else** statement check whether the **SQL Query** has returned result or not

Try this and let me know if it works or not

I basically just used a function **mysqli_num_rows** which returns the number of rows fetched by query and followed by conditional to check

```
$sql = "SELECT enBody FROM page WHERE pageName='wine'";
$result= $db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       print_r($row);

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: It returned 0 results. When I try the same on phpMyAdmin SQL, it returns 1 row...very strange

Comment: @Marius Did you use the exact same query as told here in phpmyadmin sql

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing **Object oriented style** with  **Procedural style**.

While using Object oriented style you should not use mysqli_* functions as these belongs to Procedural style.

For Procedural style refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

For Object oriented style refer: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

For you code:

**Object oriented style:**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT enBody FROM page WHERE pageName='wine'";

if($en = $db->query($sql)):
    /* fetch associative array */
    while($enOutput=$en->fetch_assoc($en)) :
        $enDisplay=$enOutput['enBody'];                 
        echo $enDisplay;
    endwhile; 
    /* free result set */
    $en->free();
endif;
```

Also, for **fetch_assoc**, refer: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php